# Show collection of items in one XamDataGrid column

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I use infragistics XamDataGrid, show collection of items in one column (use listView as CellValuePresenter ControlTemplate). The problem is that I can't filter this field. As filter I want to use distinct values of items in field collections.

Could anyone suggest how to change field filter style to filter field with collection of items?

Comment: Are you using label icons or a filter record?  If I understood correctly you want to populate the filter with distinct values of items from all of the lists in the column.  If you do this, what does filtering do?  Filter out the records in the grid that doesn't have that item in the list?